# Receive a live video stream from a raspberry pi cam on a flutter application

Tags: flutter, tcp, gstreamer, vlc, rtp

I have a gstreamer server that streams a flux video from a raspberry pi with the command:

raspivid -t 0 -w 1920 -h 1080 -fps 30 -b 2000000 -awb fluorescent -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=0.0.0.0 port=5000

I am trying to use vlc as a client to get the stream,but i can't get it to work even with an sdp file. I want to get it to work with vlc because flutter have a vlc pluginn. If i can get it with vlc, i can get it on my flutter mobile application with th vlc plugin. I am a beginner with gstreamer and flutter. So can you help me to get the stream with vlc ? If no, can you help me to find another way to get it on my flutter application? I think this stream is RTP over TCP. I want to confirm it because i am confusing the terms rtp rtsp rtcp ? Can someone help me to understand them a little more? If i use the url tcp:@x.x.x.x:5000 with vlc i don't get an error,but i have a blank screen?

Best regards,

Safouane

Comment: You are sending over TCP with a GStreamer private protocol. There is no RTP involved here, so it cannot work.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch  in the command i am doing rtph264ay. I payload encoded H264 video into RTP packets and then i send them with tcp so it is rtp over tcp.

Comment: No, you have encapsulated RTP into GDPAY. No one will recognise that this is RTP except GStreamer. There is no RTP over TCP, unless you tunnel RTP into the RTSP control channel which involves yet another completely different stack.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch ah ok. Thanks. So how do i tunnel the rtp into the rtsp control channel with gstreamer ? and if i do this can i have acces to this stream via an url type rtsp:@:x.x.x.x:port_number ?

Comment: Yes, you need a RTSP server for that. GStreamer offers a library and sample code for that.

Comment: Florian Zwoch. I succeed and I have access via gstreamer to the video streaml. But when I use vlc i have only the first frame and it is blocked after that. I use the url rtsp://ip_adress:8554/test/ to have access to the stream. Do you have an ideo why I get to see only the first frame with vlc  and not the whole stream although I had an access to the stream with gstreamer on the client side ?